# How can I create a linkable heading using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create a linkable heading element by using Javascript. So far it creates an element but it doesn't contain link. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
    function create2() {

    var heading = document.createElement("H2");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "https://www.google.com";
    heading.innerHTML = "Heading Test";
    heading.appendChild(link)
    document.body.appendChild(heading);
}

create2();
```

Comment: You need to add text to the link if you want it to be shown in the document! Inspect the element and you'll see that your code works just fine

Comment: Change `heading.innerHTML = "Heading Test";` to `link.textContent = "Heading Test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code, you can use `appendChild` on `heading`.

**Note:** I am also using `link.innerText` instead of `heading.innerHTML`.

```js
function create2() {

  var heading = document.createElement("H2");
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "https://www.google.com";
  link.innerText = "Heading Test";
  heading.appendChild(link)
  document.body.appendChild(heading);
}

create2();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Will accept your answer in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add text to the link.
This is a bit ugly, but explains what you need.

```js
    function create2() {

    var heading = document.createElement("H2");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode('link text');
    link.appendChild(text);
    link.href = "https://www.google.com";
    heading.innerHTML = "Heading Test ";
    heading.appendChild(link)
    document.body.appendChild(heading);
}

create2();
```